# How can I estimate mu and sigma parameters for logNormal distribution with the data of quantiles in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the data:

```
[11043.000000   14565.625000    15901.000000    18104.0 22458.000000    26990.000000    31825.600000    38803.500000    42934.285714    47751.111111    64975.333333]
```

for the quantiles

```
[0.1,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.9]
```

and I need obtain estimated values for mu and sigma of a logNormal distribution using python.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scipy lognorm fitting to histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940726/scipy-lognorm-fitting-to-histogram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first fit function to you data, then extract parameters:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

y_data = [11043, 14565, 15901, 18104, 22458, 26990, 31825.6, 38803.5, 42934.285714, 47751.111111, 64975.333333]

# fit data
sigma, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(y_data, floc=0)

# get mu
mu = np.log(scale)
```

Output:

```
mu = 10.186710603314205
sigma =  0.5326712155979726
```